# Unable to find a database entry even when it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I am trying to query a Medium which can have many likes and comments associated with it.

Code I try to use right now is this: `medium = Medium.joins(:comments, :likes).find(params[:id])`

This will throw an error: `Couldn't find medium with 'id'=2`

If I remove the `:likes` from my join clause, it will successfully find the medium(medium with id 2 DOES exists actually).

The faulty query:

> `Medium Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "media".* FROM "media" INNER JOIN "likes" ON "likes"."medium_id" = "media"."id" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."medium_id" = "media"."id" WHERE "media"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]`

Working query:

> `Medium Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "media".* FROM "media" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."medium_id" = "media"."id" WHERE "media"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What SQL is executed by the query that works, and what SQL is executed by the query that doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem is that the medium with id 2 doesn't have any associated likes. The `join` method generates a SQL statement with an INNER JOIN to the given table, and this will not return any results unless there are records in both tables.

What you really need here is a SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN so that records in the 'left' table (mediums) are returned even when there are no corresponding records in the 'right-hand' table (likes), something like:

```
Medium.joins(:comments).
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON likes.medium_id = mediums.id').
  find(params[:id])
```

You might also need to do the same for the join to `comments` if this is also an optional association.

Comment: Just wondering? Does rails have a built in method of doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Using `includes` instead of `joins` does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: You can use `includes` instead of `joins` but the query generated won't necessarily be a LEFT OUTER JOIN. In general `includes` will perform a second query to fetch the data for the association, unless there is a condition on the association, e.g. `where(mediums: { foo: 'bar' })` in which case ActiveRecord will generate a single query with a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the includes method is indeed much better suited for the job I am trying to accomplish.